# Is there is a way that I can download only a part of the dataset from huggingface?

Tags: dataset, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I'm trying to load (peoples speech) dataset, but it's way too big, is there's a way to download only a part of it?

```
from datasets import load_dataset

from datasets import load_dataset

train = load_dataset("MLCommons/peoples_speech", "clean",split="train[:10%]")
test = load_dataset("MLCommons/peoples_speech", "clean",split="test[:10%]")
```

Using ("train [: 10%]") didn't help, it still trying to download the entire dataset...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you consider using the [stream feature in `Datasets`](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/stream)?
It allows you to stream data from HuggingFace's Hub without having to download the dataset locally.

```py
from datasets import load_dataset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
# you get a dict of {"split": IterableDataset}
dataset = load_dataset("MLCommons/peoples_speech", "clean", streaming=True)
# your preprocessing and filtering
...
train_dataloader = DataLoader(dataset["train"], batch_size=4)
valid_dataloader = DataLoader(dataset["validation"], batch_size=4)
train_steps_per_epoch = 500
# training loop
for n in range(5):
    for i, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        # if you only want to do a limited amount of optimization steps per epoch
        if i == train_steps_per_epoch:
            break
        # train step
        ...
```

I hope it helps.